# VBA Excel: How to make a selection from fixed cell till text to be found?

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection-sort

I need to make a selection from cell "A8" to a cell that contains the word "endofsample".
That word can be anywhere in the worksheet.

Comment: In VBA you can use `Find()` to locate the word you're looking for. Check the docs for help with that function.

Comment: this belongs on superuser.com more than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
Sub test()
    Set INFO = Cells.Find(What:="endofsample", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)
    If INFO Is Nothing Then
    Else
    End If

    INFO.Select
    Range("A8", ActiveCell).Select
End Sub
```